# Checking if table already exists, but it's not working receiving error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataTable"

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Checking if table already exists, but it's not working: receiving error “Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataTable”.

here is the code

```
Sub TABLES_CHK()
    Try
        tbl_lbl.Text = "TABLES EXISTS: " & DoesTABLEExist("server=localhost; username=root; password=*****; database=*****;")
        If DoesTABLEExist("server=localhost; username=root; password=*****; database=*****;") = False Then
            Exit Sub
            Using CON As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; username=*****; password=*****;  database=*******;")
                Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("CREATE TABLE `airtech_db`.`employees`(" &
            "`Employee_ID` INT Not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,FATHER_NAME VARCHAR(45) NULL," &
            "DOB VARCHAR(45) NULL,DOJ VARCHAR(45) NULL,POSITION VARCHAR(45) NULL,EMP_STATUS VARCHAR(45) NULL," &
            "SALARY VARCHAR(45) NULL,EOS VARCHAR(45) NULL,REMARKS VARCHAR(45) NULL," &
            "PRIMARY KEY(`Employee_ID`))", CON)
                    CON.Open()
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    adapter.Fill(dt)
                    CON.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
        tbl_lbl.Text += " -TABLES CREATED: " & DoesDBExist("server=localhost; username=root; password=*****;")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Function DoesTABLEExist(DBConnectionString As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString)
        Dim ADAPTER As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From information_schema.tables" &
                                 " Where table_schema = 'airtech_db' And table_name = 'employees' LIMIT 1;", conn)
        Dim DT As DataTable, TABLECHK As Boolean

        conn.Open()
        ADAPTER.Fill(DT)
        MsgBox(DT.Rows.Count)
        If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            TABLECHK = True
        Else
            TABLECHK = False
        End If
        conn.Close()
        Return TABLECHK
    Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: This site provides a preview of questions and answers for a reason. If you click the submit button when you question looks like a dog's breakfast, you're just not trying to help us help you.

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Comment: You will need to use a MySqlCommand and ExecuteNonQuery to execute the table creation code. Using a DataAdapter is a bad idea for some SQL operations ;)

Comment: Please put `"server=localhost; username=root; password=*****;"` into some sort of globally-accessible string so that if it happens to change then you only need to change it in *one* place, not in lots of places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporairily remove the `Try` so you can see what line is causing the error.

Database objects that expose a `.Dispose` method expect that this will be called because they may be using unmanaged resources that need to be released. This happens in their `.Dispose` method. A `Using...End Using` block will handle this for you even if there is an error.

There is no need to create a `DataAdapter` or a `DataTable`. Do not pull data from the server that you don't need. You only need the count. Use `.ExecuteScalar` which returns the the first column of the first row of the result set as an object.

```
Function DoesTABLEExist(DBConnectionString As String) As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString),
           cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Count(*) From information_schema.tables
                                    Where table_schema = 'airtech_db' 
                                    And table_name = 'employees';", conn)
        conn.Open()
        RetVal = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using
    Dim TABLECHK As Boolean
    If RetVal > 0 Then
        TABLECHK = True
    Else
        TABLECHK = False
    End If
    Return TABLECHK
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

to check if table already exists, this code worked perfectly

```
Sub TABLES_CHK()
    Dim CON_STRING As String
    CON_STRING = "server=localhost; username=root; password=****; database=****;"
    Try
        tbl_lbl.Text = "TABLES EXISTS: " & DoesTABLEExist(CON_STRING)
        If DoesTABLEExist(CON_STRING) = False Then
            Using CON As New MySqlConnection(CON_STRING)
                Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("CREATE TABLE `airtech_db`.`employees`(" &
            "`Employee_ID` INT Not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,FATHER_NAME VARCHAR(45) NULL," &
            "DOB VARCHAR(45) NULL,DOJ VARCHAR(45) NULL,POSITION VARCHAR(45) NULL,EMP_STATUS VARCHAR(45) NULL," &
            "SALARY VARCHAR(45) NULL,EOS VARCHAR(45) NULL,REMARKS VARCHAR(45) NULL," &
            "PRIMARY KEY(`Employee_ID`))", CON)
                    CON.Open()
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    adapter.Fill(dt)
                    CON.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
            tbl_lbl.Text += " -TABLES CREATED: " & DoesDBExist(CON_STRING)
        Else
            tbl_lbl.Text += " -TABLES CREATED: False"
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Function DoesTABLEExist(DBConnectionString As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString)
        ' Dim ADAPTER As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From information_schema.tables" &
        '                         " Where table_schema = 'airtech_db' And table_name = 'employees' LIMIT 1;", conn)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From information_schema.tables Where table_schema = 'airtech_db' And table_name = 'employees' LIMIT 1;", conn)


        conn.Open()
        Dim bRet As Boolean = False
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        bRet = reader.HasRows
        If (bRet = True) Then
            'MsgBox("Table Exists")
        Else
            ' MsgBox("No more records")
        End If
        conn.Close()
        Return bRet

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: So, you took the bulk of my answer and created your own. You unaccepted mine. Wow! Did you think you would earn points by unaccepting my answer and accepting yours?

Comment: So sorry My bad, Fixed it @MARY

Comment: Thank you.. It was just a surprise after over a year.